# polymaps & poly... polygons

Tags: cartography, geojson

I've been playing with Bing Maps + Polymaps recently.

It has become apparent that Bing is the only mapping resource available to Polymaps that includes *satellite imagery*. Is this true?

I am trying to accomplish drawing *many* polygons of different sizes on a map, and filling them with different colors depending on what they represent. Furthermore, I want each of these polygons to be clickable.

I understand that to load geographical data onto a map with Polymaps, you either use .features() or .url() as part of the geoJSON object.

I have .features() working, but by using this function the polygon data must be embedded into the javascript file itself - as in:

```py
map.add(po.geoJson()
        .features([
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [[
[[-63.599925935268395,44.64018531837119],[-63.599789142608664,44.640219671024646],[-63.59973818063736,44.6401452402498],[-63.599877655506134,44.64010707058464],[-63.599925935268395,44.64018150140844]],

[[-63.59986692667008,44.639874235083376],[-63.59975695610047,44.63991431339196],[-63.599697947502136,44.63981507181532],[-63.5998159646988,44.639782627416906],[-63.59986424446105,44.6398723265918]]
        ]],
        "type": "MultiPolygon"
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "beat:05X",
      "properties": {"name": "05X"}
    }

        ]));
```

I want this data to actually come from a database and not lie statically within the javascript itself - which tells me I should use the .url() method instead - correct? And if I use the .url() method, I must pass a valid URL template that returns geoJSON... How do I go about this with my own private data? I'm familiar with PHP and mySQL - must I use a spatial database system instead?

And how does a map server like MapServer, GeoServer, and others fit into this? Could I not set up a PHP script to read these templates from the $_GET variable, query a database and return the proper geoJSON string?

I really just need some inspiration, a few pointers to set me on my way and kill some of the doubts I have. I've found myself just digging around the stackexchange and googling everything from map servers, to geo spatial databases - you name it, I've probably read about it, but I'm struggling putting the pieces together.

Long winded question but once these things are clarified, I should be in a much better position.

---

We can remove polymaps from the equation if there are substitutes.

In summary, I'm looking to take a large number of polygons from a database (PostGIS?) of all different shapes, sizes, colors, and transparencies, and plot them on a map. That's essentially it! Polymaps has vector graphics + I thought getting this on the go would be trivial given the above code... we can scrap it if you have other ideas. What *is* the best solution? My only business requirement is that Satellite Imagery be enabled...Which means we're working with Bing or Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about GeoJSON you can use any kind of database, and backend server, you want so long as it:

1. Expects to receives TMS or /{zoom}/{x-coord}/{y-coord}.json style URLs and can convert Z/X/Y in to a bounding box.

(Take a look at something like Tilestache (.org) if you want/need to see the math involved in doing that.)

2. Returns GeoJSON.

For styling , and adding interactive bits, to the data results you'll want to define a "load" function using the layer's on() method. For example:

```
var l = org.polymaps.geoJson();
l.url("http://example.com/tiles/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.json");
l.on("load", function(e){ ... });
```

The Polymaps site has lots of good documentation and example code, but I've also included the slides and sample code from a Polymaps workshop I did recently:

- http://www.aaronland.info/talks/where2011/
- http://www.aaronland.info/talks/where2011/workshop

Comment: Thank you Aaron, the links you have posted are truly indispensable. I've downloaded the files for later review, I will be referring to them when I am at the interactivity stage. 

I'm not sure Tilestache is something I require because the actual tiling is being looked after by Bing, no? The custom data I will be serving up is polygon data, not any sort of .png, .jpg, etc imagery. Is there any chance I could take a peak at ./flickr.json? Missing link. Cheers and thanks again.

Comment: I found it in the root of workshop/005-data/, thanks!

Comment: The two links are no longer reachable => Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

Answer (score 1):

[Building Interactive Maps With Polymaps, TileStache, and MongoDB: Part 1](http://web.archive.org/web/20111029031932/http://goalfinch.com/blog/2011/03/building-interactive-maps-with-polymaps-tilestache-and-mongodb) cleared everything up. It's a must read for anybody playing with Polymaps.

I found it via Henry on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/hb1f1/polymaps_loading_polygons_from_database/)

Aaron mentioned using TileStache and indeed... That is the key, I just did not see how - The above blog post is quite informative in using TileStache.